# changes to log4j2.properties file results in failure of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j2

I have installed elasticsearch(6.6.0) and CentOS 7. I want to add somemore properties for rotating logs like if size is 50MB rotate and compress. But if i add any more configuration to /etc/elasticsearch/log4j2.properties file and restart the elasticsearch server, it fails.

**My current log4j2.properties file:**

```
status = error

# log action execution errors for easier debugging
logger.action.name = org.elasticsearch.action
logger.action.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = console
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%m%n

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = rolling
appender.rolling.fileName = 
${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] 
%marker%.-10000m%n
appender.rolling.filePattern = 
${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-
%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz    
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = console
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = rolling
```

When i try to add, as it was given in elasticsearch documents this is how to add configurations,

```
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 2MB
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.age = 3D
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.condition.type = IfFileName
```

It is failing with **error** :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationException: No type attribute provided for component size
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createComponent(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:333)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.processRemainingProperties(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createComponent(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:336)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.processRemainingProperties(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:347)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.createAppender(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.build(PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:35)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:244)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator$1.visitFile(LogConfigurator.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator$1.visitFile(LogConfigurator.java:101)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:101)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:316)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:123)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:114)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:122)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84)
```

And i have a **warning** in /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_deprecation.log :

```
[2018-02-20T02:09:32,694][WARN ][o.e.d.e.NodeEnvironment  ] ES has detected the [path.data] folder using the cluster name as a folder [/data/es], Elasticsearch 6.0 will not allow the cluster name as a folder within the data path
```

Can anyone please explain how to add the configuration to log4j2.properties file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the logs states that you are missing `type` attribute for size configuration. You are also missing `type` attribute for `RolloverStrategy`.

Try below configuration -

```
appender.rolling.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size = 2 MB

appender.rolling.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.rolling.strategy.action.basePath = ${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}
appender.rolling.strategy.action.maxDepth = 1
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified
appender.rolling.strategy.action.ifLastModified.age = 3d
```

Comment: Hi @vikas, can you tell me how to disable the log rotation which is happening through log4j2.properties file? i did some digging, they have told to disable in logging.yml file but i dont find any such file in my setup. please help.

Comment: Thank you. what you suggested worked fine. :) can you please tell me how to remove date format from file pattern? if i give this, appender.rolling.filePattern = 
${sys:es.logs.base_path}${sys:file.separator}${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}-%i.log.gz. it is throwing error like, main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.  main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logger config "root".

Comment: @user2675459 If you do not want log rotation, then instead of `RollingFileAppender`, you can use `FileAppender`. It has different configuration and does not require `filePattern`

Comment: @user2675459 If it answers your question, then accept it as per these instructions - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you. i will try the `FileAppender` once.